# Java - creating an object passing an array as a parameter

Tags: java

I want to create an object from my class. My class has an array attribute, how do I pass it through the parenthesis?

This is my class:

```
private String Description;
private int[] Data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    public Key(String Desc, int[] d)
{
    Description = Desc;
    Data = d;
}
```

And this is how I create the object:

```
Key k1 = new Key("Shoham's Key", {0, 5 , 6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9});
```

Thanks.

Comment: The posted answer below is correct. Please follow the Java naming conventions, and have variable names start with a lowercase letter to improve readability of your code.

Comment: @jlordo yes, reading his question felt a bit awkward.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847915/how-to-reinitialize-the-int-array-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Key k1 = new Key("Shoham's Key", new int[] {0, 5 , 6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9});
```

Note: `new int[] {0, 5 , 6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9}` declaration is called Anonymous Array declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what **GanGnaMStYleOverFlow** said

[Java Language Specification - 10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) says:

*An array initializer may be specified **in a declaration**, or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), creating an array and providing some initial values*

**So you cannot initialize array when passing as a parameter.**

So the bottom statement is not allowed:

```
Key k1 = new Key("Shoham's Key", {0, 5 , 6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9});
```